# Lua package containing subpackages

Tags: lua, lua-api

I have written a number of modules for Lua in C.  Each of these contains a Lua userdata type and I load and use them like this:

```
A = require("A")
B = require("B")
a = A.new(3,{1,2,3})
b1 = B.new(1)
b2 = B.new(2) * b1
```

Now I would like to put both userdata types in a single shared library `AandB` that can be used like this

```
AB = require("AandB")
AB.A.new(3,{1,2,3})
```

What is a good way to achieve this?  Right now my `luaopen_*` functions look like this

```
int luaopen_A(lua_State *L) {
  luaL_newmetatable(L, A_MT);
  luaL_setfuncs(L, A_methods, 0);

  luaL_newlib(L, A_functions);

  return 1;
};
```

And is it possible then to still load only part, e.g. like this: `A = require("AandB.A")`?

Answer (score 2):

`require("AandB.A")` works if you define `luaopen_AandB_A` in your C library, which must be called `AandB.so`.

In general, `require` replaces dots with underscores when trying C libraries.

Comment: How would you make sure the library isn't loaded multiple times?

Comment: To explain my comment: if I understand correctly loading the library will add it to `_LOADED` by name, so if I load both `AandB` and `AandB.A` then this last bit is loaded twice.  I'll continue reading the Lua code to try and figure this out, but any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is to write a lua script module that pulls in both `A` and `B`. You can then require that script from your using code:

```
-- AandB.lua
return { A = require 'A', B = require 'B' }
```

If you only want to load part of your module, you can just do:

```
A = require "AandB".A
```

Comment: You can do this with C also and possibly even have all three modules in the same `.so` I think. Also if the modules are nested in the filesystem it should be possible to load the sub-modules without loading the main module and indexing a field out of it.